# How do I retry a Laravel Transaction using the manual Method?

Tags: php, laravel

Well, Laravel DB transactions provide a retry method where failed transactions can be retried, That is automatic transactions:

```
\DB::transaction(function(){
  // do your queries
}, $tries = 3);
```

How can someone handle this when using the Manual method? I can't figure out. Like

```
DB::beginTransaction();


DB::rollBack();
//retry the transaction();

DB::commit();
```

Comment: what's the purpose? why not use the first one?

Comment: I can't use the first one because I use it with shared lock(), I lock the table when one request is being handled. The first one doesn't provide room for locking

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#pessimistic-locking